# Python Pandas fill missing column with left join

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-3.8

I have following two data-frames.

df_1

| AA | BB | CC | DD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "Apple" | XYZ1 | XYZ2 |  |
| "Apple" | PQR1 | PQR2 |  |
| "Apple" | XYZ4 | PRR9 |  |
| "Banana" | XYZ1 |  | 416 |
| "Banana" | XYZ1 |  | 416 |
| "Apple" | XYZ4 | PRR9 |  |

df_lookup

| AA | XX | YY | ZZ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "Apple" | XYZ1 | XYZ2 | 429 |
| "Apple" | XYZ4 | PRR9 | 97 |
| "Apple" | PQR1 | PQR2 | 108 |
| "Banana" | XYZ1 | PQR1 | 416 |

**Expected result:**

My objective is to fill out the empty values in df_1. In other words:

```
if AA == "Apple" then 
 df_1.DD = SELECT df_lookup.ZZ 
 FROM df_lookup 
 LFET JOIN df_1 
 ON df_1.BB = df_lookup.XX, df_1.CC = df_lookup.YY
```

on the contrary ...

```
if AA == "Banana" then 
 df_1.CC = SELECT df_lookup.YY 
 FROM df_lookup 
 LFET JOIN df_1 
 ON df_1.BB = df_lookup.XX, df_1.DD = df_lookup.ZZ
```

df_1 (filled/modified)

| AA | BB | CC | DD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "Apple" | XYZ1 | XYZ2 | 429 |
| "Apple" | PQR1 | PQR2 | 108 |
| "Apple" | XYZ4 | PRR9 | 97 |
| "Banana" | XYZ1 | PQR1 | 416 |
| "Banana" | XYZ1 | PQR1 | 416 |
| "Apple" | XYZ4 | PRR9 | 97 |

I tried the following so far

```
apple_merged = pd.merged(df_1, df_lookup, left_on = ["BB", "CC"], right_on = ["XX", "YY"])
df_1[(df_1["AA"] == "Apple")]["DD"] = apple_merged[(apple_merged.AA == "Apple")]["ZZ"].values
```

I got the following error in my actual code:

> ValueError: Length of values (501) does not match length of index
> (602)

Which seems to suggest that the shape of the data is different on the opposite side of the assignment, 501 v/s 602. But if I really did left join, should the row counts not be the same for me in this case?

Comment: What to you expect the final result to look like?

Comment: Please post your expected output.

Comment: @piRSquared & Mayank : Added expected result DataFrame example in addition to queries. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly use `merge()` method so here we are going with default i.e inner join:-

```
df=df_1.merge(df_lookup,how='left',left_on=['AA','BB'],right_on=['AA','XX'])
```

Now fill values of 'DD' and 'CC' on the basis of 'YY' and 'ZZ' by using `fillna()` method:-

```
df['DD']=df['DD'].fillna(df['ZZ']).astype(int)
df['CC']=df['CC'].fillna(df['YY'])
```

Now all your values are filled so we have to drop extra column by `drop()` method and pass columns parameter a list:-

```
df=df.drop(columns=['XX','YY','ZZ'])
```

Now if you print `df` you will get your expected output:-

```
    AA       BB     CC      DD
0   Apple   XYZ1    XYZ2    429
1   Apple   PQR1    PQR2    108
2   Apple   XYZ4    PRR9    97
3   Banana  XYZ1    PQR1    416
4   Banana  XYZ1    PQR1    416
5   Apple   XYZ4    PRR9    97
```

**Edit: If df_lookup did not have column AA,**

```
df=df_1.merge(df_lookup,left_on=['BB'],right_on=['XX'])
df['DD']=df['DD'].fillna(df['ZZ']).astype(int)
df['CC']=df['CC'].fillna(df['YY'])
df=df.drop(columns=['XX','YY','ZZ'])
```

Niw if you want to remove duplicates use:-

```
df=df.drop_duplicates()
```

Comment: Added expected result DataFrame example in addition to queries. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I'd take a look. If df_lookup did not have column AA, what changes would you make?

Comment: Updated my answer based on your query....kindly have a look

Answer (score 1):

When you merge two dataframes in pandas, you have have to pass a `how =` argument, otherwise pandas defaults to an inner join. The error is then caused because you have 501 values in your inner joined `apple_merged` dataframe and 602 in `df_1`.

Link:  https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
d = {'XX':'BB','YY':'CC', 'ZZ':'DD'}

#column for rename
df2 = df_lookup.rename(columns=d)
#left join by defined columns
df = (df_1.merge(df2, how='left', on=['AA','BB','CC'], suffixes=('','_'))
          .merge(df2, how='left', on=['AA','BB','DD'], suffixes=('','_')))

#replaced original columns by added columns with _
cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.endswith('_')]
df = df.combine_first(df[cols].rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip('_'))).drop(cols, axis=1)
print (df)
       AA    BB    CC     DD
0   Apple  XYZ1  XYZ2  429.0
1   Apple  PQR1  PQR2  108.0
2   Apple  XYZ4  PRR9   97.0
3  Banana  XYZ1  PQR1  416.0
4  Banana  XYZ1  PQR1  416.0
5   Apple  XYZ4  PRR9   97.0
```

Comment: I am curious ...  If `df_lookup` did not have column `AA`, what changes would you make?